# iPhone - Add an email account from my app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add an email account from code in the list of accounts to use it later in my app (like iCloud or Gmail accounts). It is possible???

Thank you for advance.

**EDIT:**

I found the `ACAccount` class, with this class I will do that??

**EDIT 2:**

Now, I'm saving the user and password in the keychain. This is a good alternative or no?

Comment: Don't forget to mark top answer and / or upvote answers that have helped you. Others facing the same issue will want to know what solved the problem and those answering questions deserve the rep points. If no answer answered your question. Comment on them to ask further details

Comment: I always do it. Don't worry. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible on a non jailbreaked iOS device. This has to be done by the user manually.

Edit:
If you have gained user and password from the user (legs way) storing it in the keychain is the optimal procedure.

Comment: If I use the class `ACAccount` I will do that?

Comment: ACAcount won't help setting up a full email account

Answer (score 2):

As Volker stated, you can't do it on a non jailbroken device.

The `ACAccount` class that you refer to is mostly used to get/store credential from a previously configured Facebook, Twitter, Sina Weibo, Trecent Weibo account in your iPhone, which is not the case.

Apple can't grant access to Mail account both read/write. 
You can only send an email within your code, by using the [Message UI framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html).
A valid example on how to use it can be found [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-create-email-attachment/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want send an email, only take the user and password to access into the inbox.

Comment: No, ask the user. If he allows you to, you can do that. But otherwise the inbox belongs to the user and only him.